# Why particular ng-class syntax is not working?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

**UPDATE:** *The original question suggested that the 4th example (down below) did not work. However, it is the correct syntax (why mine was not working I never figured out). So even though this question no longer is warranted, I will leave it for reference because it does show, in one convenient place, different syntaxes for angular's ng-class (also note that syntax 3 and 4 are in fact the same). Also, there is a [plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/TX45o7mgDFCulJxt7vLO?p=preview).*

---

I am using `AngularJS v1.5.0`. I am needing a conditional class setup, and so I started with what I found via google (see my last *NOT WORKING* example). When it did not work, I opted for other ways, each of which did work.

So my question is why does my last example not work?

**WORKS**:

```
data-ng-class = "[ 'A' ,  my_array[0]=='b'?'B':'C' ]"
```

**WORKS**:

```
data-ng-class = "[ 'A' , { 'b' : 'B' ,
                           'c' : 'C' ,
                           'd' : 'D' ,
                           'e' : 'E' ,
                           'f' : 'F'
                          }[my_array[0]]
                 ]"
```

**WORKS**:

```
data-ng-class  = "[ 'A' , { 'B' : (my_array[0] == 'b') 
                          }
                  ]"
```

**NOT WORKING**: *(UPDATE: this does work ... but I am leaving it for reference)*

```
data-ng-class  = "[ 'A' , { 'B' : (my_array[0] == 'b') ,
                            'C' : (my_array[0] == 'c') ,
                            'D' : (my_array[0] == 'd') ,
                            'E' : (my_array[0] == 'e') ,
                            'F' : (my_array[0] == 'f')
                          }
                  ]"
```

Comment: please provide a demo that reproduces issue.

Comment: ... does that syntax look correct? ... if you believe that that syntax should work, then that tells me something important ...

Comment: Not really sure. I've never mixed array/object.... I would change last one to just a map object and make `{'A':true, 'B' : my_array[0] == 'b'..... 'F'....}` and forget the array. Or use a controller function and put the business logic where it really should be

Comment: I made a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TX45o7mgDFCulJxt7vLO?p=preview), but the plunker works as expected ... so now I'm not really sure ... going to take a break ... I might end up deleting this post , because apparently something else is going on ...

Comment: Well that's one of the main reasons for asking for scaled down demo. Often find your own problems or find out that issue is not related to what you expected. Could be child scope issues or numerous other potential ones

Comment: Also known as [mcve]